# GridLayout on Android studio not found

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I was writing a calculator app on Android studio and I need to use GridLayout to set up and arrange the buttons but I can't find GridLayout on the palette window. 
How can I add it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You don't necessarily need a `GridLayout`

You can use a `RelativeLayout` and connect your buttons by some XML attributes.

The XML attributes you have to use are:

1. `layout_alignEnd`
2. `layout_alignStart`
3. `layout_alignTop`
4. `layout_alignRight`
5. `layout_alignLeft`
6. `layout_alignBottom`

You can use this example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
    android:text="5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:text="6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:text="8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
    android:text="9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonadd"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="+" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonsub"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonadd"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonadd"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonadd"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonadd"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonadd"
    android:text="-" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonmul"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonsub"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonsub"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonsub"
    android:text="*" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="." />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button0"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonC"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
    android:text="C" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttondiv"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonmul"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonmul"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonmul"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonmul"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonmul"
    android:text="/" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttoneql"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttondiv"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttondiv"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:text="=" />
```

**And the result is**

[image]

Source: https://crunchify.com/how-to-create-simple-calculator-android-app-using-android-studio/

Comment: Thanks I will try this out

Answer (score 0):

GridLayout and GridView has been sent to Legacy in Palette.

[image]

*Though one should try not to use this as RecyclerView is a better option*